# BMO1 2003/04 Question 2 - Geometry Prolem

Tags: geometry, contest-math

$ABCD$ is a rectangle, $P$ is the midpoint of $AB$, and $Q$ is the point
on $PD$ such that $CQ$ is perpendicular to $PD$.
Prove that the triangle $BQC$ is isosceles.

Clearly, we need to prove that $BC=BQ$ or $\measuredangle{BCQ}=\measuredangle{CQB}$.

After a bit of angle chasing, a bit of Pythagoras, a bit of trig, I'm still not very close to proving either. I have an expression for $BQ$ using the cosine rule, but it's pretty messy and I'm unsure I can unscramble the mess and make it equal $BC$.

If anyone could come up with a proof, or at least a hint, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: There's a nice proof of this using vectors. Have you tried using vectors?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not so comfortable with vectors, I can't see anything in particular, I was wondering if I may be able to exploit the fact that $CQ$ is perpendicular to $PD$, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: draw a line from $B$ parallel to $DP$. This will intersect $CD$ at its midpoint and then...

Comment: Aha, I see now, I guess I was going after proving that $BC$ was equal to $BQ$ directly, too strongly, I didn't even consider trying to prove it like that. Lesson learnt. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is an outline of the vector method:

Let $\overrightarrow{AB}=2\underline{a}$ and $\overrightarrow{BC}=\underline{b}$

Then $\overrightarrow{PQ}=\lambda(\underline{b}-\underline{a})$ and $\overrightarrow{CQ}=-\underline{b}-\underline{a}+\lambda(\underline{b}-\underline{a})$

Now using scalar product, we have $\overrightarrow{CQ}.\overrightarrow{PD}=0$

Recalling that $\underline{a}.\underline{b}=0$, you should get $$\lambda=\frac{b^2-a^2}{a^2+b^2}$$

Now work out $\overrightarrow{BQ}$ and then work out $\overrightarrow{BQ}.\overrightarrow{BQ}$ and you get $b^2$

And that's it.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. As I said, I have only done a bit of work on vectors, I couldn't understand why $\overrightarrow{PQ}=\lambda(b-a)$. Also, what calculations did you perform when making use of the scalar product, I only really know what to do when we're working in components.

Comment: PQ is parallel to PD and hence is a multiple of the vector PD. The dot product can be evaluated without using components : here all you need is $a.a=a^2$, $a.b=0$ because they're perpendicular, and you multipy out brackets in the usual way.

Comment: I get you now. Just one last thing though, so $\overrightarrow{BQ}=\overrightarrow{PQ}-a$? Doing the algebra, I think I get $\overrightarrow{BQ}=\frac{b^3-2ab^2-a^2b}{a^2+b^2}$, not the $b$ I was hoping for, have I gone wrong somewhere?

Comment: Sorry I'm being lazy with vector notation. The correct expression for $\overrightarrow{BQ}$ is $\frac{\underline{b}b^2-2b^2\underline{a}-a^2\underline{b}}{a^2+b^2}$

Comment: Am I right in thinking the $ab$ terms cancel and we can say $b$ times by the denominator equals the numerator. Hence the required result?

Comment: From the expression I gave you in my previous comment, work out $\overrightarrow {BQ}.\overrightarrow {BQ}$  and you get $b^2$

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply, but I think I get it all now, your help has been much appreciated.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

Let the reflection of the point *C* about point *B* be *C'*

Then let the midpoint of *DC* be *M*

It's pretty clear that since *CB* = *BC'*, *DM* = *PB*, and $\angle$*PDM* = $\angle$*C'PB* (corresponding angles) that $\triangle$*DPM* $\cong$ $\triangle$*PC'B*

Now notice that the line *QB* is a median of the right triangle $\triangle$*C'QC*, specifically the median from the right angle, thus *QB* = $\frac{1}{2}$*CC'* = *CB*

Therefore $\triangle$*BQC* is isosceles

Answer (score 0):

I did:

set $\measuredangle{ADP} = \beta$

$\measuredangle{APD} = 90 - \beta$ (because angles in triangle sum to $180$)

$\measuredangle{QDC} = 90 - \beta$

$\measuredangle{QCD} = \beta$

$\measuredangle{BCQ} = 90 - \beta$

notice opposite angles in quadrilateral $PQCB$ sum to $180$, so $PQCB$ is cyclic.  Now draw $PC$.

$\triangle{APD}$ is congruent to $\triangle{PBC}$ by SAS. So,

$\measuredangle{BCQ} = \measuredangle{PDA} = \beta$

$\measuredangle{QCP} = \measuredangle{BCQ} - \measuredangle{BCP}$ = $(90-\beta) - \beta = 90-2\beta$

If we set $\measuredangle{QBC} = \alpha$ then

$\measuredangle{PBQ} = 90 - \alpha$

$\measuredangle{PBQ} = \measuredangle{PCQ}$ (because they are angles in the same segment both subtended by the chord $PQ$)

$90-\alpha = 90 - 2\beta$

$\alpha = 2\beta$

Therefore,
$\measuredangle{BQC} = 90 - \beta$ (using the sum of angles in $\triangle{BQC}$)

so, $\measuredangle{BQC} = \measuredangle{BCQ}$ meaning that $\triangle{CBQ}$ is isosceles.